# How to make a button listen again after click?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpText);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        updateQuestion(random.nextInt(mdata.questions.length));

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(button1.getText().equals(correctAnswer)){
                    updateQuestion(random.nextInt(mdata.questions.length));


                } else{
                    gameOver();

                }
    });

 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(button2.getText().equals(correctAnswer)){
                    updateQuestion(random.nextInt(mdata.questions.length));

                } else{
                    gameOver();

                }
            }
        });
```

I was making a quiz app. I created a method, updateQuestion(), which takes a random integer to show questions from array. I am facing problem that when a user clicks the button, it works fine for first time. When Second question pops up, button doesn't listen for answer. On repeated clicks, button work sometimes. Please help, sorry for poor english

update question code -

```
public void updateQuestion(int num){
        dpText.setText(mdata.getQues(num));
        button1.setText(mdata.getAlia(num));
        button2.setText(mdata.getPari(num));
        correctAnswer = mdata.getAnswer(num);

    }
```

game Over code -

```
private void gameOver(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder
                .setMessage("Game Over")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("New Game",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                finish();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Exit",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: You mean neither updateQuestion() nor gameOver() is called again?

Comment: you should show updateQuestion() and gameOver() methods

Comment: `onClick` method inside `setOnClickListener` is called every time you click the button. There seems to be an issue with your code logic.

Comment: If answer is right, I call update question(); if answer is wrong i call gameover(). In gameOver method, i just make an alert box for new game or Exit. All works fine, just buttons stop listening after 1st question. Button sometimes work after repeated clicks.

Comment: second question should have button2 onclicklistener right.

Comment: sorry, your information is very unclear, so maybe you can provide more. "repeated click" means? works after second click? "sometimes" means? Clicking a hundred times and it works only once?

Comment: if you try to do System.out.println("button1 is clicked"); when you click the button1, every time u click, logcat should have printed "button1 is clicked" 1 time. isn't that true?

Comment: may be problem is in your updateQuestion() or gameOver() methods, show them here in your question

Comment: if you doesn´t make a typo in your post, the second button onClickListener is in your first button onClickListener....that´s the problem...

Comment: it is not your onclick listener not working, put some print out when click triggered, you will know the listener is working. The problem is how u get the correctAnswer in updateQuestion

Comment: Everything works fine, app chooses questions randomly from array. App update question when I press button with right answer. When I press wrong answer an alert box appears with new game and Exit options. Both options works fine. But when second question appears with answers and I press button with correct answer, nothing happens. I press  button 2- 3 times, button works and update question again. Then again same problem occur with new question. The button doesn't listen to answer on 1st click and pressing button several times, the question is updated again. I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you put System.out.println("button1 is clicked");  in your onClick in button1  and System.out.println("button2 is clicked");  in your onClick in button2. When you said the button does not react to you click, check logcat, does the printout appear? It thats appear when you click, you have rule out is not the button not reacting, is your code has some logic issue